# How to retrieve username, email etc.. from user Pointer using parse cloud

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying fetch user fields such as username, email..etc from user pointer `{"result":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"kArFHAxDNn"}}`

```
  Ex:-  voted_userIds =  results_poll[i].get("voted_user_ids");
         voted_userIds[0].get("username");
         voted_userIds[0].get("email");
```

nothing is returning, it just return empty `{"result":""}`

I am facing this issue past 2 days. Could anybody help me ?

Updated:-

```
// Use Parse.Cloud.define to define as many cloud functions as you want.
// For example:
Parse.Cloud.define("pollResults", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Poll");
  var userData = new Parse.Query("User");
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  userData.equalTo("objectId", request.params.userId);

  //FETCH A USER BY ID
  userData.get(request.params.userId, {
    success: function(object) {

        //POLL LIST
         query.include('voted_user_ids');
        query.equalTo("user", object);
          query.find({
            success: function(results_poll) {
            var voted_userIds='';
            var message = '';
                for(var i =0; i < results_poll.length; i++){

                        if ((typeof results_poll[i].get("voted_user_ids") !== "undefined") && (results_poll[i].get("voted_user_ids") !== null)){
                            message = results_poll[i].get("voted_user_ids")[0].get("username");
                        }

                }
              response.success("--->"+message);
            },
            error: function() {
              response.error("no results found");
            }
          });

  },
    error: function() {
      response.error("no results found");
    }
  });



});
```

Note:- voted_userIds contains array of user pointer.

Comment: Have you fetched the object?  Also, in cloud code, use the master key to be able to read the user..  If this doesn't help, post more code (do you have the pointer as a string or a parse object, what is returning that json structure that is empty, etc.)

Comment: I just posted my code, Note:- voted_userIds contains list of user object. I dont know why it is termed in Cloud code as "user pointer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `voted_user_ids` is an Array column, you can just `include()` it in the query, e.g.:

```
query.include('voted_user_ids');
```

This will allow you to access all properties of each user.

Also you may need to use the master key to read other User accounts if you have locked down your permissions (which is advisable), simple add this line before you run your query:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

Comment: I updated my code using include and Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();. But still i am not getting username ?

Answer (score 1):

2 queries not necessary to get reference to an Array of pointer inside a field (voted_user_ids)

If that has an array of pointers to a class, then the first query will return it and 2nd query not needed....

```
   //POLL LIST
    query.include('voted_user_ids');
    query.equalTo("user", object);
      query.find({
        success: function(results_poll) {
```

review docs on getting a pointer in a flat, single query.You should have your pointer refs in line in the json response from the first query.